# Generate DDL with IDENTITY columns

Tags: oracle12c, enterprise-architect

Using Enterprise Architect version 13.0.1309, I'm designing a database model to be used with Oracle 12c. I want to generate a DDL script from my model that uses [the "new" IDENTITY column type](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/identity-columns-in-oracle-12cr1) instead of the explicitly created sequences and triggers.

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE identity_test_tab (
  id          NUMBER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
  description VARCHAR2(30)
);
```

However, I either can't find the option in EA or it is not supported. Which one is it?

Comment: did you find any solution for this problem?

Comment: @Muka I honestly can't remember anymore. Changes jobs twice since then. But if I had found a solution around that time, I would've posted it here. So probably not :(